# Scala Spark: Order changes when writing a DataFrame to a CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two data frames which I am merging using union. After performing the union, printing the final dataframe using df.show(), shows that the records are in the order as intended (first dataframe records on the top followed by second dataframe records). But when I write this final data frame to the csv file, the records from the first data frame, that I want to be on the top of the csv file are losing their position. The first data frame's records are getting mixed with the second dataframe's records. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is a the code sample:

```
val intVar = 1

val myList = List(("hello",intVar))

val firstDf = myList.toDF()

val secondDf: DataFrame = testRdd.toDF()

val finalDF = firstDf.union(secondDf)

finalDF.show() // prints the dataframe with firstDf records on the top followed by the secondDf records

val outputfilePath = "/home/out.csv"

finalDF.coalesce(1).write.csv(outputFilePath) //the first Df records are getting mixed with the second Df records.
```

Comment: Can you try finalDF.cache() before  finalDF.show()

Comment: Coalesce(1) ensures only one partition, but not only one core in an executor. Number of cores in an executor(if more than 1) executes a single partition in parallel manner. Hence there is possibility of both files mixed because of being written parallel. Limit cores to 1 and executor to 1 might solve your issue. I am not exactly sure about thread parallelism if will be there in each core(if there, again both files records mixes ... but, my assumption is thread parallelism also exists ).